# How many shares does she own?

Tags: arithmetic, applications

Jasmin Coleman bought 5,000 shares of GE stock. She held them for 6 months. Then Jasmin sold 190 shares on monay, 450 shares on Tuesday and again on Thursday, and 900 shares on friday. The average shares of stock jasmin still owns is worth $48 per share.

Determine (a) how many shares does Jasmin still own?
(b) What is the total value of Jasmin stock after the sales?

Comment: What color are Jasmin's eyes?

Comment: A different problem: On Sunday, Imelda owned $5000$ pairs of shoes. She threw $190$ pairs away on Monday, $450$ pairs on each of Tuesday and Thursday, and $900$ pairs on Friday. How many pairs of shoes does she still own after that?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 1):

$$5000 - 190 - 450 - 450 -900 = 3010$$
$$3010 * \$48 = \$144480 $$

Comment: Omg ! thank you. i was attempting to solve it this way but i was not sure

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is less obvious than it looks.  GE's stock split several times, most recently a 3-for-1 split on May 8, 2000.  There was a time on June 22, 2000 when the stock price was approximately \$48 (the low for that date was \$47.94).  So if she had bought 5000 shares about six months before that date, then sold 190, 450, 450 and 900 shares in June, she would still have 13010 shares, not 3010.